# connect() can't find signal function

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qt-creator, slot

I'm trying to set the `connect()` like this:

```
QObject::connect(&webControl,
                 SIGNAL(Ui::MainWindow::loadFinished(bool)),
                 &w,
                 SLOT(Ui::MainWindow::loadFinished(bool)));
```

in `main()` function but it give the error:

> QObject::connect: No such signal
>   QWebView::Ui::MainWindow::loadFinished(bool)

`w` and `webControl` are declared like this:

```
MainWindow w;
QWebView webControl;
```

And here's my files:

**mainWindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void loadFinished(bool arg1);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

**mainWindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::loadFinished(bool arg1)
{
}
```

Why I'm getting this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: You don't need all that qualifiers for SIGNAL and SLOT macro: SIGNAL(Ui::MainWindow::loadFinished(bool)). Just do SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool))

Comment: There is indeed no signal. You just take the slot and put it as both signal and slot.

Comment: @AlexanderVX: It worked for the `connect()` call in `main()` but not from another method of `MainWIndow` class. It give same error

Comment: which qt version do you use?

Comment: @Megasa3: 3.3.0: http://prntscr.com/8ee09s it's version which uses mingw rather than MSVC

Comment: You're using Qt version 5.4.0. Qt Creator is just an IDE, not Qt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `QWebView webControl;` webcontrol is a qwebview and your signal is not in QWebview, but in MainWindow. You need that signal in QWebView. That is why its complaining about a signal that can't be found.

**EDIT**

You have a problem knowing what is a slot, and what a signal. Thy are two different things. A signal is like an alarm. An slot is the receiver and it works as a normal function.

If you want your webControl var to be the sender, then you have to declare the signal like this in y our QWebView.h class :

```
signals:
    void yourSignalName(bool arg1);
```

and use the connect like this:

```
QObject::connect(&webControl,
             SIGNAL(yourSignalName(bool)),
             &w,
             SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));
```

Comment: You mean my slots and signals must be defined in a class that inherit from `QWebView` to the slot work for the `webControl`?

Comment: I mean that the logic of the connect is: object who wants  to send the signal, the signal name,  object who receive the signal and do something on the slot, slot name. So.. in your connect, you have: `&webControl, SIGNAL(Ui::MainWindow::loadFinished(bool)),` which means that webControl will send a signal, but then you say that the signal is loadFinished from Ui::MainWindow which has no logic. That loadFinished should be declared min the webControl class

Comment: My confusing was also because I'm coming from C# and events works a bit different there. I'm new to QT

Comment: np, then you understand it now? :) It was difficult for me too on the beggining but then its all logical :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `QWebView *webView;` to your `mainwindow.h`:

**mainwindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QWebView *getWebView() const;

public slots:
    void loadFinished(bool arg1);
    void setWebView(QWebView *webControl);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebView *webView;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
...

QWebView *MainWindow::getWebView() const
{
    return webView;
}

void MainWindow::setWebView(QWebView *webControl)
{
    webView = webControl;
    QObject::connect(webControl,
                     SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),
                     this,
                     SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));
}
```

If you really need declaration of `QWebView` in `main.cpp` then pass pointer to `setWebView()` function:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    QWebView webControl;
    w.setWebView(&webControl);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the new Qt5 syntax (which is optional):

```
QObject::connect(&webControl, &Ui::MainWindow::loadFinished,
                 &w, &Ui::MainWindow::loadFinished);
```

more on the new syntax: http://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: he is  using qt 3.3 so its a bad idea

Comment: @Megasa3 I'm using a kind of different QT, it uses MinGw by default. It's based on QT 5.4.0. I guess that's why this compiles but didn't solve the issue

Comment: oh! sorry! I saw it uses MinGw but didn't know that was based on 5.4.0. sorry! my fault!